# Loading DLL file from a path in Powershell script

Tags: mysql, powershell, dll, automation

I'm trying to write a script that has to access a DLL file (MySql.Data.dll) from a folder in the Desktop(New Folder). I use the variable `$DLLFilePath = $home + '\Desktop\New Folder\MySql.Data.dll')` to set the path. But it's not working with `[void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($DLLFilePath)` giving the error `Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."`.

Is there someway to get the DLL file loaded in `LoadFrom`?

Comment: Is `$home` set to something valid?  Does it result in the correct path to the DLL?  What happens if you hard code the full path in the call to `LoadFrom()`

Comment: $home variable in PoweShell is a cool feature that  will automatically resolve to C:/Users/<Username>. DLL is in the New Folder in Desktop. I can't hard code the path because I'm developing a script that can can be run on different computers so I can't hardcode the path as the Username will differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like PowerShell doesn't allow strings or variables in LoadFrom(). So I used a simple workaround:

1. Copy the DLL file to a new location like C: drive
2. Hardcode the path to the DLL file in LoadFrom()
3. Delete the copied file in C: after use.